# Variable number of CollectionContainers in CompositeCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Lets say I have a Canvas on which I want to display a number of X and Y samples which belong to a variable number of groups.

I have a ViewModel which has an ObservableCollection of groups. I can display all samples of a  chosen group by binding an itemscontrol to one of the classes. But now I want to show all samples of a the groups combined. I've found the CompositeCollection which allows this, but I cant seem to find out how to bind the groups collection to the CompositeCollection so I can add and remove groups and automaticly update the canvas.

Comment: can you show some code pls. datatemplate is the key if you wanna display different objecttypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CollectionViewSource` supports the concepts of groups, and the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` supports the display of hierarchical data. Between the two you should be able to create a solution in my opinion